# How can i go back to a specific game state?

Tags: java, game-engine, 2d-games

Editing a question Because I have no longer privileges to Ask One.

So I have a Game Name Space XD:
where

```
Game(main) class -> run()(gameloop)|-> render(gui) -> handler.render()(all Gameobjects render)         
                                   |-> tick() -> handler.tick()(all Gameobjects tick)
```

lets imagine a condition where player is in level 3 And on user input i want the game state the same as it was when player was in level two like points decreased, 
health at that particular moment etc..

I tried one solution

```
 if(level == 3){
          this.game = previous_game; // i define previous_game = this.game; when level was 2. But nothing changed.  
           this.handler = handler; // same as up;
           this.HUD = HUD;// heads of display but nothing was changed except i saw a black screen i thing because the background is black(background is black) please help i dont see any answers of this.
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: `text.replace('public', 'oranges');`  your actually doing nothing with the return..

Comment: can u please open this question @Xufox

Comment: can u please open this question  @Saptal

Comment: @J.JOE why did you removed the tick mark?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal because I edited question and now this is completely about game development in java and if i tick it  will not shown in home

Comment: @J.JOE you should have asked a new question instead of editing the one which is already answered and accepted

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Actually i lose the rights to ask a new question:-')

Comment: @J.JOE I can understand that but editing this question will not help you anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the assignment of the new replaced value to `text` as `text = text.replace('public', 'oranges');`:

You can further use `code[i].innerHTML = text;` to change the initial HTML with the replaced HTML.

```js
window.onload = (function(){
   var code = document.getElementsByClassName('code');
   for( i=0 ; i < code.length ; i++ ){
      var text = code[i].innerHTML;
      text = text.replace('public', 'oranges');
      code[i].innerHTML = text;
      console.log(text);
   }
})
```

```html
<p class = "code"> public stasdfadtic void main sdfdsa </p>
<p class = "code"> public static void main </p>
```